# Problem Implementing if loop in the program. Read comment for more information

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop, nested-loops

I am new to programming and was trying to write a program. I want this program to keep asking user to enter a number greater than `int lowerValue` (Zero in this case) until the user enters a value greater than the `lowerValue`. I have made a function `greater` to do this.

When I replace if(statement) the while(loop) and keep the rest of the code same program works fine. but with if statement the program asks
user to enter value twice and then ends.

```
package com.company;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static int greater(int lowerValue, Scanner input){
        int number = 0;
        number = input.nextInt();
        if(number < lowerValue){
            System.out.println("enter value greater than " +lowerValue);
            number = input.nextInt();
        }
        return number;
    }


    public static void main(String args[]) throws RuntimeException {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int loweValue = 0;
        System.out.println("Enter value greater than " + loweValue);
        int number = greater(loweValue, input);

    }

}
```

Comment: Search "java while loop and for loop" on the web

Answer (score 0):

Use while loop instead of using if conditional statement if you want to execute a block of code repetitively until the condition is true.

```
package com.company;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static int greater(int lowerValue, Scanner input){
        int number = 0;
        number = input.nextInt();
        while(number < lowerValue){
            System.out.println("enter value greater than " +lowerValue);
            number = input.nextInt();
        }
        return number;
    }


    public static void main(String args[]) throws RuntimeException {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int loweValue = 0;
        System.out.println("Enter value greater than " + loweValue);
        int number = greater(loweValue, input);

    }

}
```